# Can Git fetch from remote-tracking branches of a remote repository?

Tags: git

Typically the source of `git fetch` is  `ref/heads/*` of the remote repository.

Is it not allowed to fetch from remote-tracking branches i.e. `ref/remotes/*` of the remote repository?

Comment: Are you wanting to fetch from a remote other than the origin?

Answer (score 6):

Of course!

A "normal" fetch is `git fetch origin refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`

This is telling the current repository to connect to `origin`, get a list of `refs/heads/*` and store the references in the local `refs/remotes/origin/`.

You can tweak this to get the `origin:refs/remotes/*` like so:
`git fetch origin refs/remotes/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`

It's worth noting that the usefulness of this depends on your knowledge of the remote you're talking to: You get the remote name that was configured in the remote you're referencing, but you don't get the details about that remote. In other words you could well end up seeing a new entry `refs/remotes/origin/origin/master` but what exactly that's tracking would be a mystery unless you know what `origin/origin` really is.

Comment: Although you don't know what the remote's tracking branch is tracking, that just means that you "doubly don't know" what the branch is about.  I.e. if the remote's "origin/master" is some unknown thing, the remote's corresponding local "master" is that unknown thing with local hacks applied that could be further diverging at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it not allowed to fetch from remote-tracking branches i.e. ref/remotes/* of the remote repository?

Yes you can.

Git doesn't care where the source is coming from. You can fetch, pull & merge form different branches and origin at the same time.

Consider this:

You have a big project where you have several sub-contractors who are working on the same project but each one is changing code in a different path.

Once the work is done you need to merge it all to one big project.

**How?**

```
git merge origin1/A origin2/B origin3/3 ... originN/N
```

Again, git doesn't care where the content comes from.